# laravel ancho y alto storage

Tags: laravel, imagen

Cuál sería el código para saber el ancho y alto de una imagen en un directorio

Actualmente lo hacía con `getimagesize()` pero quería saber si se podía hacer con **storage** de **laravel**.

Algo así como:

```
Storage::size('file1.jpg');// este es para saber el tamaño
```

**ojo**: No estoy subiendo una imagen ,quiero saber el ancho y alto de una imagen que ya tengo guardada.
Espero puedan ayudarme. Cualquier idea que ayude a resolver mi problema será bien recibida.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias utilizar [Intervention/image](https://github.com/Intervention/image) que es muy util para el tratamiento de imagenes.

**Instalacion**

Ejecutas desde tu consola `composer require intervention/image`

**integracion en Laravel**

Añades a tu **Service Provider**: `Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class` y a tus **Facades**:`'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class` ambos se encuentran en el archivo ubicado en **config/app.php**.

Posteriormente ya puedes utilizarlo.

**Obteniendo el ancho**

`$width = Image::make('public/foo.jpg')->width();`

**Obteniendo el alto**

`$height = Image::make('public/foo.jpg')->height();`

> **Nota** : Ambas funciones retornan un entero

También encontraras muchas funciones útiles al momento de manejar imágenes en tu proyecto